# jQuery, new line and enter button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using following code for textarea:

```
$('#ajaxSendMessage').live('keyup', function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        controller.sendMessage($(this).val(), $("#ajaxAnswerTo").val());
    }
});
```

This code works, but `$("#ajaxAnswerTo").val()` have new line characte when I click enter...
For example: I entered: helo world and then moved cursor to helo world, updated it to hello and clicked enter. The result code will be: hell\no world.

How to remove this \n?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to catch it on `keydown`

[see it working here on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rpgEb/)

---

If you want to go the regex route, you can simply use

```
$("#ajaxAnswerTo").val().replace(/\r?\n/, '');
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple Regular Expression should do the trick:

```
$("#ajaxAnswerTo").val().replace(/\r?\n/, '');
```

Comment: this can be simplified to `/\r?\n/`. ECMAScript supports the [`?` quantifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refflavors.html) (0 or 1)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#ajaxSendMessage').live('keypress', function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        event.preventDefault();
        controller.sendMessage($(this).val(), $("#ajaxAnswerTo").val());
    }
});
```